# Room One to Many Foreign Key exception - FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)

Tags: exception, kotlin, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I get this exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)) when using Room with One to Many. Here are my classes:

**Main Model (Parcel):**

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
@Entity(tableName = "parcels")
data class Parcel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "parcel_key")
    var parcelKey: Long,
    @Embedded
    var type: ParcelType?,
    (...)
)
```

**Child Model (Document):**

```
    @Entity(
        tableName = "documents",
        indices = [Index(value = ["linked_parcel_key"])],
        foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
            entity = Parcel::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("parcel_key"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("linked_parcel_key"),
            onDelete = CASCADE
        )]
    )
    data class Document(

        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "document_key")
        val documentKey: Long,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "linked_parcel_key")
        var parcelKey: Long,
        val title: String,
        (...)
   )
```

**And this is my ParcelWithDocuments class:**

```
data class ParcelWithDocuments(
    @Embedded
    val parcel: Parcel,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "parcel_key",
        entityColumn = "linked_parcel_key"
    )
    var docs: List<Document>
)
```

Why do I get that exception? What do I do wrong?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings, names & line numbers & with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com' and read many hits & answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.